# Code was already redeemed ... But where?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api

I am stuck / block on this point, I keep on having this error message 'Code was already redeemed'
3 steps :

- Getting the authorization URL (SignetLogin)
- Calling it and retrieving the authorization code (SignetAuth)
- Getting the refresh token and calling google API (SignetInsert)

When I try to use the API I always get this error message : Code was already redeemed'.

I ask for some help, what's wrong and where can I find some tips about it ? What did I missed ?

Thanks - Gregoire

```
def SignetLogin
    auth = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
    :authorization_uri =>     'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
    :scope =>                 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
    # :state =>                 'useful_dynamic_string',    # What is that ?
    :redirect_uri =>          'http://localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback',
    :client_id =>             $client_id,
    :client_secret =>         $client_secret
    )
    redirect_to auth.authorization_uri.to_s
end


def SignetAuth
    $code = request['code']
    auth = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
    :token_credential_uri =>  'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    :redirect_uri =>          'http://localhost:3000/SignetInsert',
    :client_id =>             $client_id,
    :client_secret =>         $client_secret,
    :code =>                  request['code']

)
end


def SignetInsert
    auth = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
    token_credential_uri:       'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    redirect_uri:               'http://localhost:3000/',
    # redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google_oauth2/callback',
    :client_id =>               $client_id,
    :client_secret =>           $client_secret,
    :code =>                     $code
    )
    # puts auth.fetch_access_token!

    calendar = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
    calendar.authorization = auth
    calendar_id = 'primary'

    @result = calendar.list_events(calendar_id,
                               max_results: 10,
                               single_events: true,
                               order_by: 'startTime',
                               time_min: Time.now.iso8601)
end
```

---

Comment: You get this error when calling `calendar.list_events` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I get the error on calendar.list_events call .
Also I don't fell comfortables with the arguments for OAuth2::Client.new

Answer (score 1):

I cant help you much with ruby but i can tell you what "Code was already redeemed' means.

When you authenticate to Google there are three steps.

1. User is shown a consent form
2. Assuming the user accepted consent an `authentication code` is returned to the calling client application.
3. The calling client exchanges the `authentication code` for an `access token` and sometimes a `refresh token`.

The access token can then be used to access the API. Access tokens expire after an hour and you can use a Refresh token to request a new access token.

The authentication code that you get back as part of the auth flow can only be used once to get the access token and refresh token.  `"Code was already redeemed'` means that you are trying to use a code you have already used.

Like i said i dont know much about ruby but this might help [google apis ruby client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client)

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I don't think it's a ruby error, more a miss-understanding of the OAuth API and how (and when) making the calls. I will investigate in the direction you told me and give you some feedback. 
By the way thanks for your answer

Comment: I suspected the same thing.  Oauth can be hard to grasp in the beginning

Comment: Ok, one next step, and again thanks for your patience. step 1 Ok, user consent fine, I get the code ($auth.code = request['code']) then just after I call $token = $auth.fetch_access_token! and get { "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Code was already redeemed." } again. So : 1 Ok, I get redirect to my auth page and get the code, I insert this code in auth and call fetch_access_token and Boum :-(( I am getting crazy

Comment: This should walk you threw the different calls https://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your tips and answers, you gave me the way ! 
It's not that easy, but I did it, with your help, thanks again

So, the answer is multiple :

1/ The refresh token is not served every time, only the first time, this url [allow you to dis-authorize your app](https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/permissions) and have it again in the answer

2/ this article [gave some tips](http://gmile.me/simple-google-auth/) on how to start but definitivly down't give you the 'right' way [2](http://gmile.me/simple-google-auth/)

3/ As far as I understood, using a 'clean' request (see step 1)

- $auth = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new and you retrieve an authorization_uri, you redirect to (don't forget to_s)
- Google display it's form, asking for authorization
  ***- Google redirect the user on your server, you retrieve the access_token and the refresh_token THE FIRST TIME ONLY (see step 1 to de-authorize and having again your refresh_token
  -*** 
  and, because you (or I) just can't guess it :

`$auth.code = request['code']
$auth.grant_type = 'authorization_code'
$token = $auth.fetch_access_token!`

you can use your token and so on

it's not that easy but I hope facebook will not be too different